# Cannot get selected radio button selected

Tags: jquery

I have a form:

```
<form>
<label>Login Method</label>
<ul>
    <li>
        <label class="">Safeword</label>
        <input type="radio" value="safeword" name="auth-method" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Multi-Factor</label>
        <input type="radio" value="multi_factor" name="auth-method" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Digital Certificate</label>
        <input type="radio" value="digital_cert" name="auth-method" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <button name="auth-method-submit" value="continue" class="continue">Continue</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to manually set the inputs to be checked when an `li` is clicked. On submit, I want to get which input has been choosen. Heres the JS:

```
var selectedInput, selectedLabel;

$('form li *').click(function(event){

if (selectedLabel) {
    selectedLabel.removeClass('selected');
}

if (selectedInput) {
    selectedInput.prop("checked", false);
}

selectedLabel = $(event.currentTarget.parentElement).find("label");

selectedInput = $(event.currentTarget.parentElement).find("input");

selectedLabel.addClass('selected');
selectedInput.prop("checked", true);
});

$('button').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();

console.log('val is');
console.log($("form input[type='radio']:checked").val());
});
```

The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LmeL5ybt/4/). If you check the console however, you will see:

```
val is 
undefined
```

Why can I not get the value selected?

Comment: [Simplified code in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmeL5ybt/4/)

Comment: Even more tidied up and working: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LmeL5ybt/6/